# How can I find with Twitter "GET search" tweets by "text" field only?

Tags: twitter

How can I find with Twitter "GET search" tweets by "text" field only? Not by the "from_user" and others.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the q parameter with the standard search endpoint?

Something like this: `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=searchTerm`

Comment: No. For example I have tweet: "How can I find with Twitter "GET search" tweets by "text" field only?". My user name is "Shurikosha". I find: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=shurikosha&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed' and I have several results including my "How can I find..." because this tweet from the user "Shurikosha". But the text of this tweet doesn't include word "Shurikosha".

Comment: Not sure then - maybe you just have to iterate through the result and drop anything from your own username?

Comment: I tried it with other people user names. The results were the same.